# Drools workbench: How to make use of global variables inside rule file

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

I am using Drools workbench 7.17 integrated with Kie execution server. I have created project using workbench which consists of data models, rule file and global definitions.

I want to use global variable to set some value in it if rule is executed and retrieve global variable value. I can achieve this using spring boot application where we add global variable inside session using `kieSession.setGlobal("response", response);`  and retrieves it using `kieSession.getGlobal("response")`. I tried replicating same with workbench but I am getting *null pointer exception* when I am trying to set value in global variable. Below is my rule file:

```
package com.myspace.drools_ruleengine;
import com.myspace.drools_ruleengine.Person;
global com.myspace.drools_ruleengine.Response response;
dialect "mvel"
rule "If person age >= 18 then person is adult"
no-loop
when
    $p: Person(age >= 18)
then
    response.setMessage("Adult");  // throwing error- null pointer exception
end
```

I have created **global definition** and added response as a alias for Response class. Is there anything required apart from this ? I am using **Kie Server Rest API** to insert facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize global variable while   sending requests for rule execution, like as:

```
<batch-execution>
<set-global identifier="obj">
  <com.sample.Test/>
</set-global>
<insert>
  <com.Person>
     <name>abc</name>
   </com.Person>
</insert>
<fire-all-rules/>
</batch-execution>
```

Try with this approach